# why does the Stm32f103c8t6 Board need an ST-Link V2?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded

Well I am starting a course on embedded systems on udemy and it seems I need an M3 or M4 ARM cortex MCU so I can follow on the projects. The course itself recommend the Discovery board, but I was aiming for the stm32f103c8t6 [Datasheet](http://www.ram-e-shop.com/ds/general/STM32F103_blue.pdf)

It seems that there's no much information about the board in terms of programming on the stm32 IDE as everyone is using it with the Arduino IDE .

I was wondering If I will need additional hardware beside it like an st link v2 ( which I don't know it's purpose yet ,but that's what I got after some searching ). in order to be able to program and debug nicely along the course

The first part of the course is in the following link in case someone needed more details [The Course](https://www.udemy.com/course/microcontroller-embedded-c-programming/?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=udemyads&utm_campaign=DSA_Catchall_la.EN_cc.ROW&utm_content=deal4584&utm_term=_._ag_88010211481_._ad_437497337004_._kw__._de_c_._dm__._pl__._ti_dsa-21781902600_._li_21468_._pd__._&matchtype=b&gclid=Cj0KCQiA6Or_BRC_ARIsAPzuer9Z8Xfaubq5xDrFzYNgnJc6MUQKZhWWwO7bM64TKAv59EVwqKkFFFsaAjQVEALw_wcB)

Comment: Which 'stm32f103c8t6' board are you looking at?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I edited the post

Comment: I think you will find that debugging with the STlink is vastly better than just using the Arduino IDE. You should get the board that is recommended for the course.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I'm on budget for such board actually. The instructor said that any board from ST will do just fine so this version is ok. I'm just wondering if I will need additional hardware as there's almost no resources talking about programming this board without the arduino IDE

Comment: you do not need any additional hardware to program the board ... it is programmed through the USB port ... i do not know what you need for debugging

Comment: @jsotola So what is the purpose of the st link if it  can be programmed with it's USB port ?

Comment: You might be better of getting something like a [NUCLEO-F303RE](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/stmicroelectronics/NUCLEO-F303RE/5052640). It has a STM32F303 device (ARM Cortex M4) as well as an on-board ST-LINK/V2 for programming & debugging.

Comment: Eww, did you pay for the class yet?  Looking at the class description you will have to unlearn a lot of that stuff to be successful long term.

Comment: Do not assume the blue pill can be programmed via the usb port, and if you have bugs in your program you can make that interface no longer work.  The discovery board has a separate debugger (like buying a separate stlink) on the board, and unless you physically damage the board you can reprogram it independent of bugs in your code.  With an stlink or a usb to uart board you can also reprogram the blue pill independent of bugs in your code.

Comment: @old_timer I have no experience with the stm32f103c8t6 ... reasearch on the internet indicates that the board can be programmed from the Arduino IDE by using the on board USB connection

Comment: @jsotola  that's only enabled by a 3rd party bootloader. Many of the later STM32's with USB have support for it in the ROM bootloader, but the 'F103 is an early one, and does not.

Comment: It's quite unlikely that you can use "any" M3 or M4 MCU for the course unless you have a very high degree of experience; in reality the core matters very little, 90% of the effort goes into dealing with peripherals and they can be extremely different even within a vendor's offerings.  The M3 STM32F100's for example have quite a bit different peripherals schemes than most of ST's newer chips.

Comment: @jsotola yes, there is a well maintained firmware/bootloader that is available for it, but if it didnt come pre programmed you have to get it onto the board (chip) using uart or swd, then you can use the usb and play in the arduino sandbox.  (or use dfu-util) but if you before you start or eventually have to have the other paths you could just use those.  Depends on if the goal is the arduino sandbox, with something that outperforms an avr, or if the goal is to just play with mcus...

Comment: As Chris points out and I mentioned somewhere, the stm32s are not all equal.  The class description points out  essentially they are teaching you to write the code at the make your own library level, how to use C to point at control and status register and manipulate them, which is all very good.  But

Comment: with experience with these parts that we have, they do not all use the same addresses and the details of how each of the peripherals work vary, so the class may say to change bit 3 in blah register but if you dont have the same card then it may be some other bit in some other register or it might not have that peripheral at all, so without the same card/chip the exact examples are not expected to work and will take some level of re-write to work on whatever you buy...if different.

Comment: If you want to do this and continue to do work with this type of hardware at this level you need to invest the fives and tens of dollars here and there for jumper wires and usb to uart adapters and one or more swd/jtag solutions.  These things used to be dozens to hundreds to thousands of dollars now many of them are sub $10.  But like anything else you need a toolbox of tools and baremetal mcu work is not just a collection of software tools, you need some hardware too...

Comment: Okay I hit the offensive part of the lectures.  there is still a lot of good stuff here, 99% of it is just C language stuff.  But there are an endless list of false statements or dangerous ways to do things, which you can only find with experience.  Note that a large percentage of the population uses these bad habits.  And some percentage of those get badly hurt by them eventually (sometimes it takes a decade or two).  There is nothing in the class that you cannot learn from countless other examples.

Comment: @old_timer can you give an example of such bad habits taught in this course please

Comment: + this just the first part there's maybe 8 or 7 other parts its a series of courses

Comment: One example is bitfields.  Also as mentioned before not understanding the difference between the language and implementation.  Relying on implementation defined features of the language and writing code based on that.  The lecture contradicting itself.  As with any course, anything you see on this site, anything you see me write.  Never trust it 100%, always have doubt and questions, form your own opinion.  It shows solutions that a lot of people use, but that also cause a lot of people to fail and be surprised...wander around stackoverflow for a while, it wont take long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does the Stm32f103c8t6 Board need an ST-Link V2?

You do not "need" it but you "need" a way to write your program to the flash on the part.

> Well I am starting a course on embedded systems on udemy and it seems I need an M3 or M4 ARM cortex MCU so I can follow on the projects. The course itself recommend the Discovery board, but I was aiming for the stm32f103c8t6 Datasheet

I watched most of the (first) class so far.  It is almost all about the C language in general but does walk you through the chip document to show you registers and bits, as well as how to write code to access them.

The part on the stm32f4 and the part on the stm32 blue pill are not the same and are not compatible.  The cortex-m3/4 is not relevant with respect to addressing and using the peripherals.  So the concepts and tools will all work the same, the exact addresses and bits will not.

> It seems that there's no much information about the board in terms of programming on the stm32 IDE as everyone is using it with the Arduino IDE.

I would have to disagree with this in a few ways, I would say percentage wise nobody is using the Arduino IDE.  The truth is somewhere between everyone and no one.  The cost of the blue pill makes it easy for people to use with all of the various solutions, not limited in any way to the Arduino.  Most folks are not using Arduino.

st and arm have plenty of information along with countless examples across the internet about how to program these mcus.  And as a result these stm32f4discovery boards as well as countless examples that are specifically for these blue pill boards.

The class uses the ST IDE and the stm32f103 is still an available product so I cant see that one of their tool choices supports this part.  The blue pill is just a breakout board with a crystal, so while they may or may not
support the board (knowledge of where the led is??) there should be support for the part.

> I was wondering If I will need additional hardware beside it like an st link v2 ( which I don't know it's purpose yet ,but that's what I got after some searching ). in order to be able to program and debug nicely along the course

The (authentic) stm32f4 discovery has an stlink on the board, so you do not need to buy one separately.

The blue pill does not have debugger hardware on it, you have to buy that separately.  The stlink of any flavor is just one possible solution, it is not the only solution, so therefore not "required".

When you read the documentation about the stm32 chip and the arm cores (go to the arm website) you find that there is an swd (single wire debug) interface to the arm core which the stm32 parts will expose.  Stlink is essentially a usb protocol that you use to talk to a debugger (in this case external hardware between your development computer and the target mcu).  The stlink solution is a path essentially to the swd protocol so that with software that speaks the stlink protocol you can talk to the arm core.  With access to the arm core you can do, among other things, write your program to flash so that it can be run when reset or powered on.

There are other paths, usb protocols if you will to hardware (boards) that then speaks swd for you.  Most notably but not limited to jlink and ftdi based boards in particular those with MPSSE.

The stm32f103 part also includes a bootloader (software) from st, not an arm thing.  This provides access through that interface to write your program into the flash. (also documented on st's website) And there are too many to even mention solutions here, costing from around a dollar to maybe 15.

The blue pill may come pre programmed with an application that works as a bootloader that speaks a well known usb protocol that the Arduino IDE also supports.  But this is the same application flash area where your programs will live so if you mess this up then you cannot use this interface anymore you have to use one of the ones above, with external hardware, to reprogram this bootloader into the application flash so that you can to back and try again using the Arduino IDE.   The stm32f4 discovery does not have this problem there is a separate debugger and target mcu the debugger hardware can reprogram the target mcu independent of bugs in your code (those that do not destroy the hardware).

So back to the title question:

> why does the Stm32f103c8t6 Board need an ST-Link V2?

You do not "need" it but you "need" a way to write your program to the flash on the part and that might desire an SWD solution of which the stlink is one (but not the only one).

The stlink version should not matter.

SWD is not your only path in, and stlink is not the only swd solution.  There are lower cost solutions to program the blue pill (that may or may not be compatible directly with the arduino ide).

The class or this first one is at least mostly C language stuff not using the board but using your computer.  When it does use the card it does rely on the stlink interface.  Where the lecturer will click a button on the GUI and a second or seconds later the board is programmed and the led is blinking or whatever.  That few seconds might take you a few weeks to get working for you depending on ability to find the right info and experiment, it might take me an afternoon for example.  But I hope, but not necessarily expect the IDE to "just work".  You might get lucky.

This class moved on quickly into adding another piece of hardware that perhaps you want to buy to add to the stm32f4discovery.  One thing I often struggle with is sticking to someones sandbox, I eventually build my own.  Although the board is expensive relative to perfectly valid alternatives for the same goal, for the class I would recommend you buy the hardware used by the class.  At the same time IMO you can watch this class without any MCU boards and then make your own decision.  You can take that knowledge and attempt to use the Arduino IDE if you wish and the blue pill, or search for folks using the ST IDE and the blue pill.

IMO the blue pill boards are low quality I have ordered many and had a number of them arrive non-functional.  Likewise there is an stm32f4 discovery clone that is low cost, it does support dfu-util, but like the blue pill might just work, but no surprise if it does not.  And I have had a percentage of those be bad or marginal.  So while trying to learn you may also be struggling with hardware issues.  The nucleo boards are so far pretty good and you do not need additional hardware to make the mcu work and one would expect there to be direct support in one of the st IDEs.  Same goes for similar boards from the other vendors (ti, atmel/microchip, nxp, etc).

Comment: The thing is I don't where to start or even what to search for to start learn any of that So I searched for a course a bit where I can put myself on the road and I got this recommended I have no idea if it will be good or bad yet but nope I didn't pay for it yet I was just asking some specialist about which to take this one or the one on edx from UTAustinx if you have any recommendation that will be appreciated

Comment: Lots of errors and  false claims sprinkled through the above, but it's far too rambling to address specifically

Comment: I re-wrote the answer.

Comment: I am just going to clean this up, have spent too much time on it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use those generic boards, I think you should get an ST-LINK V2 or clone (the latter is inexpensive from China and the originals are not too expensive either) **and** a USB<->TTL serial module.

STM32CubeIDE supports ST-LINK and Segger J-Link and I would not recommend the latter unless you have a big budget.

I believe you could also use another ST board with the debugger built-in and jumper it over.

All in all, if your main experience is with Arduino type systems, it might be easier to use the recommended board, as the software is fairly complex.

Comment: You mean If I got the blue pill with the st programmer and the serial Module you mentioned. there will be additional software needed in order to completely simulate the recommended board ?

Comment: STM32CubeIDE  is the IDE that is recommended in the course. It is fairly complex.